# Why does the browser tell me the parse is not defined even if I have imported it in the head of the HTML file?

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

I'm trying to connect my HTML files with the parser server. I followed the direction of the back4app guides and added the following code to the head of index.html. But the browser kept telling me Parse is not defined.

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/parse/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.serverURL = "https://parseapi.back4app.com";
    Parse.initialize(
        "MY_APP_ID",
        "MY_JS_KEY"
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please test the code below?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parse/2.1.0/parse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() { 
      Parse.initialize("APP_ID", "JS_KEY");
      Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/';
  }
/</script>
```